# Toggle Airport Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

Is there any way of toggling Airport using Cocoa?

Comment: You can probably do it via AppleScript, no ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the CoreWLAN framework. To disable the interface,

```
#import <CoreWLAN/CoreWLAN.h>

NSError *error = nil;
CWInterface *wif = [CWInterface interface];
BOOL setPowerSuccess = [wif setPower:NO error:&error];
if (! setPowerSuccess) {
    NSLog(@"error whilst disabling airport: %@", error);
}
```

To enable the interface, pass `YES` to `-setPower:error:`.